# unexpected behaviour of dictionary membership check

Tags: python, dictionary

An unhashable object cannot be inserted into a dict. It is documented, there is good reason for it.

However, I do not understand why it affects a membership test:

```
if value not in somedict:
    print("not present")
```

I was assuming that a membership test can return only `True` or `False`. But when the `value` is unhashable, it fails with `TypeError: unhashable type`. I would say `True` should be the correct answer of this `not in` test, because the `value` is clearly not contained in `somedict` and it is fully irrelevant that it cannot be inserted.

Another example:

```
try:
    result = somedict[value]
except KeyError:
    # handle the missing key
```

When the value is unhashable, it fails with `TypeError: unhashable type` I would expect the `KeyError` instead.

Also:

```
somedict.get(value, default)
```

does not return the default, but throws the `TypeError`.

---

So why `unhashable in somedict` does not evaluate to `False` and what is the correct test returning just True or False?

---

Update:

> `object.__contains__(self, item)`
>
> Called to implement membership test operators. Should return true if item is in self, false otherwise.

(from "Data Model - Python Documentation")

---

Appendix:

This is a simplified part of a user interface program, which failed when one of the arguments was a dict.

```
# args = list of function arguments created from user's input
# where "V1" stands for value1 and "V2" stands for value2
XLAT = {'V1': value1, 'V2': value2} 
args = [XLAT.get(a, a) for a in args]
function(*args)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asking-is-hashable-about-a-python-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460650/asking-is-hashable-about-a-python-value)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that the test for a potential key being part of a dictionary is done by generating the hash value of the potential key.  If the potential key cannot provide a hash value (if the object is not hashable), the test cannot take place.

You are right, in a way, that in this case the existence test could just say "no, not present" ("because it cannot be inserted anyway").

This is not done this way because it could cloak a lot of programming errors.

If you program cleanly, you will most likely never check for an unhashable object whether it is in a dictionary or not.  I. e. it requires quite an amount of fantasy to come up with a case where you actually would.  (I wouldn't say it is completely out of the question, though.)  The amount of  cases where such a check is only happening because a programming error leads to a situation where you do something accidentally, is way larger.  So the exception indicates that you should look at the spot in the code.

If you know what you are doing (maybe the case in your situation), you should simply catch that error:

```
try:
    if strange_maybe_unhashable_value in my_dict:
        print("Yes, it's in!")
    else:
        print("No, it's not in!")
except TypeError:
    print("No, it's not even hashable!")
```

If you want to combine that with your `KeyError` handling:

```
try:
    result = somedict[value]
except (KeyError, TypeError):
    # handle the missing key
```

or

```
try:
    result = somedict[value]
except KeyError:
    # handle the missing key
except TypeError:
    # react on the thing being unhashable
```

To provide another aspect which is rather esoteric:

An object might be hashable at some time and unhashable at another (maybe later).  This should of course never be the case but can happen, e. g. if the hash value relies on something external.  Despite common assumptions, being hashable is independent from being immutable (although one often relies on the other).  So an object *could* change while being part of a dictionary, and this *could* change its hash value.  While this is an error in itself and will lead to having the dictionary not working properly, this might also be a design-reason not to simply say "not present" or raise a `KeyError` but raise the `TypeError` instead.

Comment: Nice explanation, but it's cleaner and more readable to explicitly check beforehand whether an object is hashable and act accordingly. Exceptions should be for exceptions, not for an expected control flow. The same concerns using `KeyError` instead of checking for existence.

Comment: Where do you draw the line between "expected flow control" and "exceptions"?  At least in Python with its cheap exceptions, using them for stuff you really quite expect is completely normal.  In other languages (e. g. Java) the situation is different because exceptions there are quite costly.

Comment: Usually the line is somewhere around typical use case vs erroneous one. In this case it's obvious that an unhashable object is not an error (not an implementation error nor a business error), so why make it an exception? It doesn't matter whether it's cheap or not - I was referring only to readability.

Comment: @BartoszKP Asking for forgiveness is a very typical idiom in Python over LBYL…

Comment: Nice explanation, but I think you're mixing up `ValueError` and `TypeError`. Also  can you actually give an example of a *real* situation where you would want to check for a hashable object in a dict?

Comment: @Alfe This explanation sounds plausible. Could you please provide a link or other source for this design decision?

Comment: @deceze Yes, but in this case it's not "forgiving" - it's an ordinary control flow. This is misusing of EAFP IMHO. Well, I wrote "IMHO" so we might as well finish the discussion ;)

Comment: @Chris_Rands Imagine a general hashing of function results (maybe via a decorator).  That would typically use all the input (the function arguments), put them into a tuple and use this as a key in the dictionary keeping the hashed results.  If now some part of the input value is unhashable (like a list), then hashing could not be done for this kind of input and the computation needs to take place every time; but for some other inputs (like combinations of tuples, strings, numbers, etc.) it could be done and used to speed up things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check if it's hashable, if it is: try your piece of code, if not: return False. This is not an answer to your 'why' question, but at least I think it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to test a key which cannot possibly exist in a dict, it indicates a logic error or possibly a typo of you trying to test against the wrong variable. Why would you even attempt the test if it can never be true; likely you want to fix that issue in your code.

It makes sense to me to treat these as two different cases which can really aid in debugging. If you do have a case where you're mixing hashable and unhashable types and this is explicitly not in error, you should make that clear:

```
try:
    if value not in somedict:
        ...
except TypeError:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of an implementation decision. Which makes sense : unhashable type should return a specific type of error.

Imagine you implement a `Counter` class, containing a `Dictionary` which just counts objects.

```
cnt.Add(x) # adds one to the counter
cnt.Count(x) # returns the number of occurences of x as seen by cnt, 0 if x has never been seen beofreL.
```

You run it on a collection of objects and one of them happens to be unhashable, but you do not know it. Then when you want to look at the number of occurences of this object, your program will return 0, which would not be true.

On the other hand, the fact that there is a specific exception when the type is unhashable let the developer chose the behavior to implement. If there was one single exception for these two cases, you would not have this choice.

Answer (score -1):

Use it as:

```
if value not in somedict.values():
    print("not present")
```