# x not in set versus x != each element in the set?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose we have `x = ['a', 'b']`.

What is happening under the hood for the statement:

```
x not in {None, False}
```

that raises the `unhashable type: 'list'` error?

The workaround I found is to write this instead:

```
x != None and x!= False
```

but I am confused because, mathematically, both boolean expressions are equivalent.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't find a prior. It's a good question regardless.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you describe what you're actually trying to achieve in words? I suspect that neither option is really what you want.

Comment: You mean to compare the list `x` right? (As opposed to the contents of `x`?) Like  you don't mean `all([y not in {None, False} for y in x])`?

Comment: `x` is not hashable, so it cannot be in your `set`

Comment: You are trying to find whether a list object is within a set of two values (meaning whether one of the two values in the set *is a list*). Lists cannot be hashed, so cannot be part of a set, so are not comparable. What do you want that operation to do?

Comment: Is there some rationale for `[] in set()` raising an error rather than evaluating to `False`?

Comment: @Patrick Python warning you of nonsensical operations rather than quietly failing.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: Yes `[]` can't be in a `set()`. I did the same error in [\[SO\]: How to check whether a file exists? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-to-check-whether-a-file-exists/44661513#44661513)  (section 4.)

Answer (score 5):

### Rationale

Here's what the official documentation states:

1. [[Python 3]: class **set**(*[iterable]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

   > Return a new set or frozenset object whose elements are taken from *iterable*. The elements of a set **must be** [**hashable**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable).
2. [[Python 3]: **hashable**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable):

   > An object is *hashable* if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a [__hash__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an [__eq__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
   >   ...
   >   All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable; **mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are not**.
3. [[Python 3]: object.**__contains__**(*self, item*)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) (just above the anchor):

   > The membership test operators ([in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) and [not in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in)) are normally implemented as an iteration through a sequence. However, **container objects can supply** the following special method with a more efficient implementation, which also does not require the object be a sequence.

Going into [[GitHub]: python/cpython - (v3.5.4) cpython/Objects/setobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.4/Objects/setobject.c):

- Line *#1991*:

  ```
  static PyMethodDef set_methods[] = {
      {"add",             (PyCFunction)set_add,           METH_O,
       add_doc},
      {"clear",           (PyCFunction)set_clear,         METH_NOARGS,
       clear_doc},
      {"__contains__",(PyCFunction)set_direct_contains,           METH_O | METH_COEXIST,  // @TODO - cfati: MARK THIS LINE
  ```
- Line *#1843*:

  ```
  static PyObject *
  set_direct_contains(PySetObject *so, PyObject *key)
  {
      long result;

      result = set_contains(so, key);  // @TODO - cfati: MARK THIS LINE
      if (result == -1)
          return NULL;
      return PyBool_FromLong(result);
  }
  ```
- Line *#1823*:

  ```
  static int
  set_contains(PySetObject *so, PyObject *key)
  {
      PyObject *tmpkey;
      int rv;

      rv = set_contains_key(so, key);    // @TODO - cfati: MARK THIS LINE
      if (rv == -1) {
          if (!PySet_Check(key) || !PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_TypeError))
              return -1;
          PyErr_Clear();
          tmpkey = make_new_set(&PyFrozenSet_Type, key);
          if (tmpkey == NULL)
              return -1;
          rv = set_contains_key(so, tmpkey);  // @TODO - cfati: MARK THIS LINE
          Py_DECREF(tmpkey);
      }
      return rv;
  }
  ```
- Line *#627*:

  ```
  static int
  set_contains_key(PySetObject *so, PyObject *key)
  {
      setentry entry;
      Py_hash_t hash;

      if (!PyUnicode_CheckExact(key) ||
          (hash = ((PyASCIIObject *) key)->hash) == -1) {  // @TODO - cfati: MARK THIS LINE
          hash = PyObject_Hash(key);
          if (hash == -1)
              return -1;
      }
      entry.key = key;
      entry.hash = hash;
      return set_contains_entry(so, &entry);  // @TODO - cfati: MARK THIS LINE
  }
  ```
- Line *#614*:

  ```
  static int
  set_contains_entry(PySetObject *so, setentry *entry)
  {
      PyObject *key;
      setentry *lu_entry;

      lu_entry = set_lookkey(so, entry->key, entry->hash);  // @TODO - cfati: MARK THIS LINE
      if (lu_entry == NULL)
          return -1;
      key = lu_entry->key;
      return key != NULL && key != dummy;
  }
  ```

As seen from the "callstack" (presented in reversed order), in order to test for membership (`in` / `not in`), *hash* is being performed (on all code paths) on the candidate member ("*includee*"), and since the *list* instance doesn't have the *hash* functionality, the interpreter spits out *TypeError*.

### Resolution

There is a number of ways to get around this (as many others already pointed out most of them):

- Use a container that doesn't require its elements to be hashable (*list*, *tuple*)
- Test for *__hash__* member
- Wrap the membership test in a ***try*** / ***except*** block
- Use a a hashable container (*tuple*) for the element: `x = ('a', 'b')`

but (generally) these are just ways to **get around** the problem (this is my personal opinion), since if you end up comparing a list to *None* and *False*, the code (that yields that list) could use some refactoring.

Answer (score 3):

if you can enter all elements you want to test in a `set`, it means that all unhashable elements *don't* belong to your set (because you can't put them in)

You could do:

```
if x.__hash__ and x in {None,False}:
```

when object isn't hashable, `x.__hash__` is `None` (other alternatives: [Asking "is hashable" about a Python value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460650/asking-is-hashable-about-a-python-value)) and the second part isn't evaluated.

or (better ask forgiveness than permission):

```
def belongs(x):
    try:
        return x in {None,False}
    except TypeError:   # unhashable type
        return False
```

both solutions are faster than using a `list` or `tuple` (`(None,False)`), because there's no linear search involved (that is if there are a lot of elements in the test list, not true for only 2 elements)

Comment: I would argue that `try: [] in {} except TypeError: ...` would be more pythonic.

Comment: @deceze yeah, I wanted to use short-circuit. Exceptions force to create a function. There are also other alternatives in the link I provided (like testing type aganst `collections.Hashable` but I suspect this is going to be slooooow)

Comment: Exceptions don't force the creation of a function; it depends on the context in which this code is used and how verbose/concise you want it. Perhaps you can abort your entire operation when a `TypeError` occurs or doesn't occur because obviously `x` is of the wrong type…

Answer (score 1):

`{None, False}` is a set. Sets can only contain *hashable* objects, and therefore you can only test for membership of hashable objects. Lists are not hashable.

Instead, you could use a tuple to perform the same sort of membership comparison. Tuple elements do not need to be hashable.

```
x not in (None, False)
```

Comment: so if `x` is unhashable, then it's not in the set :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to do a brief comparison on membership tests on `set` vs `list`

Membership tests invoke [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) dunder(if class implement this method). So, if we write

```
>>> 1 in [1,2]
```

it will equivalent to

```
>>> list.__contains__([1,2],1)
>>> True
```

If we do:

```
>>> [1,2] in [1,2,3]
>>> False #We get False instead of TypeError here
```

But why is above case not applicable to sets? Membership tests work in a different way in list and set. Infact list and set are implemented differently. Talking about set, they are implemented using [`Hash-Table`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). This allow `sets` to perform membership test i.e. lookups in `O(1)` as compared to `list` where lookups are `O(n)`. So when `in` is performed on a set, `__contains__` try to compute the `hash` of the object that need to be looked using [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__). Since 
lists are unhashable in python, you get the error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. If you do same with list you won't get any error since list don't compute hash for membership testing.

In short membership tests cannot be performed on sets with an object that is unhashable. Generally speaking all mutable objects`(list, sets, dict)` are unhashable.