# "TypeError: unhashable type" during lookup of unhashable object in dict/set

Tags: python, hashtable, lookup

## Preface

I understand that `dict`s/`set`s should be created/updated with hashable objects only due to their implementation, so when this kind of code fails

```
>>> {{}}  # empty dict of empty dict
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

it's ok and I've seen tons of this kind of messages.

But if I want to check if some unhashable object is in `set`/`dict`

```
>>> {} in {}  # empty dict not in empty dict
```

I get error as well

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

## Problem

What is the rationale behind this behavior? I understand that lookup and updating may be logically connected (like in [`dict.setdefault` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)), but shouldn't it fail on modification step instead of lookup? Maybe I have some hashable "special" values that I handle in some way, but others (possibly unhashable) -- in another:

```
SPECIAL_CASES = frozenset(range(10)) | frozenset(range(100, 200))
...
def process_json(obj):
    if obj in SPECIAL_CASES:
        ...  # handle special cases
    else:
        ...  # do something else
```

so with given lookup behavior I'm forced to use one of the options

- [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl) way: check if `obj` is hashable and only after that check if it is one of `SPECIAL_CASES` (which is not great since it is based on `SPECIAL_CASES` structure and lookup mechanism restrictions, but can be encapsulated in separate predicate),
- [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) way: use some sort of utility for "safe lookup" like

  ```
  def safe_contains(dict_or_set, obj):
      try:
          return obj in dict_or_set
      except TypeError:
          return False
  ```
- use `list`/`tuple` for `SPECIAL_CASES` (which is not `O(1)` on lookups).

Or am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking "is hashable" about a Python value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460650/asking-is-hashable-about-a-python-value)

Comment: @quamrana: this post is not about "how to find if object is hashable", I know how to do that, it's about dict/set lookup mechanism quirks

Comment: It sounds like when python sees: `obj in dict_or_set`, then the first thing it tries is `hash(obj)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue18510) on Python bug tracker. Long story short:

if

```
>>> set([1,2]) in {frozenset([1,2]): 'a'}
```

returned `False` it will be in some way counter-intuitive since values are equal

```
>>> set([1,2]) == frozenset([1,2])
True
```

So I think I'll write & use proper utilities where situation like this can possibly occur.

---

About the roots of the error: in [CPython repo](https://github.com/python/cpython)  [`dict___contains__` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L2745) (which is a `dict.__contains__` method implementation) calls [`PyObject_Hash` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L788) (which corresponds to [`hash` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash)) -> for unhashable objects (like `{}` in our first case) calls [`PyObject_HashNotImplemented` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ab67281e95de1a88c4379a75a547f19a8ba5ec30/Objects/object.c#L780) -> generates this error.

Answer (score 1):

As you have no doubt realized, sets and dicts are very similar in their inner workings. Basically the concept is that you have key - value pairs (or just keys with a set), and the key must never change (immutable). If an object were mutable, the hash would loose it's meaning as a unique identifier of the underlying data. If you can't tell if an object is unique or not, the meaning of a set of unique keys looses it's key property of uniqueness. This is why mutable types are disallowed in sets and as the keys of a dict. With your example: `{} in {}  # empty dict not in empty dict` I think you have a slight misunderstanding, as `dict.__contains__` only checks the keys of the dict, not the values. Since you can never have a dict as a key (because it's mutable) this is invalid.

Comment: I know everything that you've written, that `key in dct` checks if the `key` is in `dct`, not in values, my question is why it raises `TypeError`, not `False` (since unhashable objects could not be in `dict` keys/`set` elements) and how to deal with that in general case

Comment: @AzatIbrakov given that logic, should this be valid? `a = [1,2,3]; print(a['key'])`. The issue I see here is one that's totally moot in a statically typed language, and a common one in dynamic languages. There are some operations that require the type to be known. I see this as a normal part of programming, and not an error with the language.

Comment: @Aaron: moot not mute.

Comment: @quamrana ty.. haven't digested my morning coffee yet :P

Comment: `__getitem__` and `__contains__` are totally different methods, so I don't think your example is somehow relevant

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I disagree, as `dict.__contains__` could be written quite accurately as `def contains(dict, key): try: dict[key]; except KeyError: return False; else: return True` By the principle of only catching the specific exception you need, this won't catch the error raised from not being able to get the hash of `key`

Comment: This type of question has actually been asked many times before [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175532/should-a-retrieval-method-return-null-or-throw-an-exception-when-it-cant-prod), and there are many opinions on the matter. Python chooses to throw an exception which favors the "don't fail silently" principle, while Lua will return `nil` for things of this nature (Lua throws very few exceptions in fact beyond syntax errors).